# How to get around peoples bad habit of double clicking in the web?

Tags: html, forms, user-input

Recently one of my clients told me something that made me to freak out. He noticed if he is clicking on the submit button in the post editor page in wordpress some of the post meta boxes are gone. I you are not familiar with wordpress post editor screen then in brief- there are some developer defined boxes called post meta box which allow developers to integrate into the post editor age without messing around the framework (which is pretty bad i guess). Any way some of the contents are saved while editing via ajax. Which data are not saved via the ajax call all are lost when my client hit the submit button twice.

I was never aware of this problem. But as soon as I looked around, I found many people who even click twice on the links provided by the search of google! I don't know how to teach people around me that in windows double click is a savior both of time and afford. But in the web single click is enough!

What i can do is change the state of the button "disabled" using javascript. That somehow helps. But now here comes my question how can i handle it if there is no javascript available?

I've seen many questions and answers to use javascript or any js library. But i'm interested to some other solutions without js because I've no control on this. Please notice this before reporting this question as a duplicate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess I will add this as a comment. Who has javascript disabled? Firefox recently removed the disable javascript option. A user who is non-savvy and double clicking buttons and links 99.99% of the time will not have javascript disabled. So disabling buttons onClick is definitely the best option.

Comment: ..and more to the point, how are you doing ajax with no javascript?

Comment: thanks a lot beiller and Greg for your comments. I didn't know that firefox removed that option. And to Greg, ajax/javascript wasn't my point. I told some story of wordpress framework. I am looking for more server side solution rather a client side. Thanks again you both for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Potential solution would be to check IPs and timestamps on the receiving end. If you've received another call from that IP in the past x amount of time exclude it, and potentially return a user prompt. If all clients are using the same IP you could also do this with session IDs but you would have to add that to the request from the client side.